# How to stop dropdown menu from pushing content down?

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, submenu

I was wondering if someone could help me make it so that the content does not drop down  without it messing the sub menu up. I tried changing the sub menu to position: absolute but that just messed up the sub menu and I also tried z-index: 2 and that didn't help.
The only other idea I would have to fix it is to somehow apply something like the position: absolute to the text but, I am not sure how to do that.
If anyone could help me I would greatly appreciate it

Comment: Here is the link to the jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Thinkgraser/t2ogvLps/10/

Comment: Please edit your question to include that link

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Add this piece of css at the end of your style file

```
    nav ul li {
        position: relative;
    }

    nav ul ul {
        position: absolute;
        width: 100%;
    }
```

For sub-menu to not push the content down it needs to have `position: absolute` style. Other bits of css is to fix the styling and sub-menu width.

Answer (score 3):

you should add following css to your code

```
nav ul li {
  position:relative;
}
//add class on sub-menu(.drop-down)
.drop-down{
  position:absolute;
  top:100%;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  z-index:1;
}
//z-index value set as your needs
```

Answer (score 0):

Make your dropdown menu's `position: absolute;` and then the element under it as `position: relative;`.

If this doesn't work, try to make both the dropdown menu and the element under it as `position: absolute;` and then set the `z-index` of the dropdown as higher than the element below it.

I made the dropdown and the element under it positioned `absolute` (both of them), and it worked. The dropdown menu is now ignoring the element under it.