# dropdown menu using CSS only

Tags: css

I'm Abdullah, and I'm new in the web development world, I'm very excited to be here and of course I'm here to ask your assistance during my journey to help understand and get better in that.
I built a nav bar with dropdown menu using CSS only, I succeeded in getting the aim but I'm stuck with 2 issues and hope to get help here.
please see attached screen recording. As you can see there are 2 issues:

1. The dropdown is pushing the text down and I want it to flow over it.
2. When hovering a navbar item the item box stretches and gets some extra width.

```css
html {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 3em;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  text-align: center;
  width: 50%;
  margin: 50px auto;
  padding: 20px 0;
}

p {
  font-size: 1.5em;
  border: 1px solid green;
  padding: 25px 50px;
  margin: 5px 25px;
}

span {
  display: inline-block;
  font: italic bold;
  color: red;
  padding: 15px;
  margin: 10px 25px;
  border: 1px solid green;
}

nav.navbar {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 15px 25px;
}

div.navbar-items {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-grow: 1;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 0 1px;
}

.item,
a {
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: aliceblue;
  padding: 12px 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: rgb(58, 122, 196);
  text-align: center;
}

ul.dropdown-items {
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0 10px;
}

a.item {
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(85, 157, 238);
}

.dropdown-items li {
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(85, 157, 238);
}

div.navbar-items:hover ul.dropdown-items {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 2px 0 0;
}

nav.navbar:hover {
  align-items: self-start;
}

a:hover {
  background-color: rgb(87, 146, 214);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css-reset.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="box-styles.css" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <nav class="navbar">
      <div class="navbar-items">
        <a href="#" class="item">Nav-01</a>
        <ul class="dropdown-items">
          <li><a href="#">I'm List No.1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">I'm List No.2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">I'm List No.3</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">I'm List No.4</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">I'm List No.5</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">I'm List No.6</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">I'm List No.7</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="navbar-items">
        <a href="#" class="item">Nav-02</a>
        <ul class="dropdown-items">
          <li><a href="#">I'm List No.1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">I'm List No.2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">I'm List No.3</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="navbar-items">
        <a href="#" class="item">Nav-03</a>
        <ul class="dropdown-items">
          <li><a href="#">I'm List No.1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">I'm List No.2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">I'm List No.3</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">I'm List No.4</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">I'm List No.5</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">I'm List No.6</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">I'm List No.7</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">I'm List No.8</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="navbar-items">
        <a href="#" class="item">Nav-04</a>
        <ul class="dropdown-items">
          <li><a href="#">I'm List No.1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">I'm List No.2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">I'm List No.3</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">I'm List No.4</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">I'm List No.5</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="navbar-items">
        <a href="#" class="item">Nav-05</a>
        <ul class="dropdown-items">
          <li><a href="#">I'm List No.1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">I'm List No.2</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Obcaecati
      voluptatum nostrum voluptatem, ea, magnam debitis iste totam earum
      quibusdam harum saepe veritatis atque sapiente sint iure, amet sunt qui.
      Assumenda?<span>IAM SPAN</span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur
      adipisicing elit. Quia sed sit rerum culpa. Veniam architecto quibusdam ut
      eum. Odio dolorum quod voluptatibus modi magnam sed ipsam vel recusandae
      animi asperiores.
    </p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to stop dropdown menu from pushing content down?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54613785/how-to-stop-dropdown-menu-from-pushing-content-down)

Comment: Not a fix but note that the [<meta>](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/semantics.html#the-meta-element) tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in any HTML specification.
 The same is true for `<link>` and all other HTML tags

Answer (score 0):

> The dropdown is pushing the text down and I want it to flow over it.

This can be achieved with absolute positioning

> When hovering a navbar item the item box stretches and gets some extra width.

The width increases to fit the dropdown menu. This is circumvented when using absolute positioning for the dropdown menu.

```css
div.navbar-items {
  position: relative;
}

ul.dropdown-items {
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0;
}
```

I commented out the unnecessary CSS declarations. The `font: italic bold;` declaration for `span` is invalid because the [`font` shorthand property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font) must include values for `font-size` and `font-family` while it may optionally include values for `font-style` and `font-weight`

```css
html {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

p {
  font-size: 1.5em;
  border: 1px solid green;
  padding: 25px 50px;
  margin: 5px 25px;
}

span {
  display: inline-block;
  font: italic bold;
  color: red;
  padding: 15px;
  margin: 10px 25px;
  border: 1px solid green;
}

nav.navbar {
  display: flex;
  /* justify-content: center; */
  /* align-items: center; */
  margin: 15px 25px;
}

div.navbar-items {
  position: relative;
  /* display: flex; */
  /* flex-direction: column; */
  flex-grow: 1;
  /* justify-content: center; */
  /* align-items: center; */
  padding: 0 1px;
}

.item,
a {
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: aliceblue;
  padding: 12px 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: rgb(58, 122, 196);
  text-align: center;
}

ul.dropdown-items {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
  /* padding: 0 10px; */
  padding: 2px 0 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
}

a.item {
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(85, 157, 238);
}

.dropdown-items li {
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(85, 157, 238);
}

div.navbar-items:hover ul.dropdown-items {
  display: block;
  /* display: flex; */
  /* flex-direction: column; */
}

nav.navbar:hover {
  /* align-items: self-start; */
}

a:hover {
  background-color: rgb(87, 146, 214);
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar">
  <div class="navbar-items">
    <a href="#" class="item">Nav-01</a>
    <ul class="dropdown-items">
      <li><a href="#">I'm List No.1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">I'm List No.2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">I'm List No.3</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">I'm List No.4</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">I'm List No.5</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">I'm List No.6</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">I'm List No.7</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="navbar-items">
    <a href="#" class="item">Nav-02</a>
    <ul class="dropdown-items">
      <li><a href="#">I'm List No.1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">I'm List No.2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">I'm List No.3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="navbar-items">
    <a href="#" class="item">Nav-03</a>
    <ul class="dropdown-items">
      <li><a href="#">I'm List No.1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">I'm List No.2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">I'm List No.3</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">I'm List No.4</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">I'm List No.5</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">I'm List No.6</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">I'm List No.7</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">I'm List No.8</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="navbar-items">
    <a href="#" class="item">Nav-04</a>
    <ul class="dropdown-items">
      <li><a href="#">I'm List No.1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">I'm List No.2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">I'm List No.3</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">I'm List No.4</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">I'm List No.5</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="navbar-items">
    <a href="#" class="item">Nav-05</a>
    <ul class="dropdown-items">
      <li><a href="#">I'm List No.1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">I'm List No.2</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
<p>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Obcaecati
  voluptatum nostrum voluptatem, ea, magnam debitis iste totam earum
  quibusdam harum saepe veritatis atque sapiente sint iure, amet sunt qui.
  Assumenda?<span>IAM SPAN</span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur
  adipisicing elit. Quia sed sit rerum culpa. Veniam architecto quibusdam ut
  eum. Odio dolorum quod voluptatibus modi magnam sed ipsam vel recusandae
  animi asperiores.
</p>
```

Comment: Thanks to this pro solution, it's short and to the point, a lot trash has been taken out from the code. I successfully Fixed the navbar to the top and set a 25px margin Left/Right, the issue is the left margin that been accepted and the right margin ignored!!